# GPS data outliers

Tags: python, vector, gps

I have set of latitude and longitude points but i am having hard time to build algorithm that could remove outlier points(shown in orange circles). What i tried is to get the vector angle between points and then remove if reach certain threshold(i.e. large angle), is there a better way? also, when i use use the dataframe in pandas, i have problem with the looping. loop when the vector is large, back to the base point(red circle) then remove until the next point which is somewhat straight. thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avHDx.png)

Here is my sample code:

> 

```html
df_4 = df_3.copy()
def angle(vector1, vector2):
    unit_vector_1 = vector1 / np.linalg.norm(vector1)
    unit_vector_2 = vector2 / np.linalg.norm(vector2)
    dot_product = np.dot(unit_vector_1, unit_vector_2)
    angle = np.arccos(dot_product)
    return np.degrees(angle)
df_4.reset_index(inplace=True)
th = 20
angle_vector = 0
idx=0
a=0
for x in range(len(df_4)):
    print('for:',str(idx))
    vector1 = [(df_4.loc[idx+1,'Longitude'] - df_4.loc[idx,'Longitude']),(df_4.loc[idx+1,'Latitude']-df_4.loc[idx,'Latitude'])]
    vector2 = [(df_4.loc[idx+2,'Longitude'] - df_4.loc[idx+1,'Longitude']),(df_4.loc[idx+2,'Latitude']-df_4.loc[idx+1,'Latitude'])]
    angle_vector = angle(vector1,vector2)
    df_4.at[idx+1,'angle_vector'] = angle_vector
    #print(angle_vector)
    print('before:',len(df_4))
    i = 0
    while(angle_vector > th & (angle_vector not in [a for a in range(86,96)])):
        df_4.drop(df_4.index[idx+1], inplace=True )
        df_4.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
        print('after:',len(df_4))
        print('while:',str(i))
        vector3 = [(df_4.loc[idx+i,'Longitude'] - df_4.loc[idx+i-a,'Longitude']),     (df_4.loc[idx+i,'Latitude']-df_4.loc[idx+i-a,'Latitude'])]
        angle_vector = angle(vector1,vector3)
        i += 1
    idx+=1
```

`

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer. The answer depends heavily on the underlying data (so what they represent). Without such knowledge we cannot really answer. (your data seems not bad, probably within the GPS errors). Is it a timeseries? But so could you print the line? (in the first circle, it is just up-down-up-down?, in such case, an average could help).

Comment: I think it can be applied to any GPS data with outliers, sorry because i just cant disclose any data because of confidentiality. THanks. Can you give some?

Comment: There are many type of outliers. Your data seems a time series: e.g. same device, nearly the same time, and ordered data. This makes huge differences on "outliers". If you take the same device on same place, and you measure for several day (and in different hours), you get different values. But if you are measuring nearly the same time, you get most of points translated the same way (think as systematic errors) . Different devices have different calculation (so artifacts with approximations). Travel with cars: more interference/multi-paths. etc.

Comment: And if you are using Android (as example), you may get errors because Google algorithms using some WiFi data (on touristic place you may "fly" on different cities, because Google hit a moving "hotspot"/tethering device. Wifi on moving cars/buses/trains. Your data, for a GPS, seems enough precise (often you have worst data), so to remove outliers you must know much more what do you expect (in your case a triangle? several segments? not changing often the bearing? Or you allow "drunken walks" ("random walk" [Brownian motions] in mathematics)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information, i have this gps data and my goal is to eliminate data points not lying on the line. i assume here that the line is straight or has 90 degree angle because it is a pipeline running on a city. but i am having trouble removing outliers, maybe because it is on spherical trigonometry. is there an issue if these are use as x y coordinates like on cartesian? thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so your algorithm make much more sense. I think in the *gis/geo-information* sister site (look on the icon on top right) you may get better answers (this is a typical example they have, here you have much more question about cleaning GPS user data). The good: they use a lot python, so you may have hints on libraries or algorithms to use.